# Change value of variable in Python decorator

Tags: python, decorator

```py
from functools import wraps

class EventCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, schedules=None, matters=None):
        self.counter = 0
        self.schedules = schedules
        self.matters = matters
        if not isinstance(schedules, list) or not isinstance(matters, list):
            raise ValueError("schedules and matter must be list.")
        if not all([schedules, matters]):
            raise ValueError("Need to set schedules and matters both.")

    def __call__(self, f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.schedules:
                if self.counter == self.schedules[0]:
                    self.schedules.pop(0)
                    if self.matters:
                        self.matters.pop(0)
            wrapper.counter = self.counter
            wrapper.schedule = self.schedules[0] if self.schedules else None
            wrapper.matter = self.matters[0] if self.matters else None
            self.counter += 1
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @EventCounter([2, 4, 8, 16], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    def reset():
        print(f'{reset.counter}: {reset.matter}')

    for _ in range(20):
        reset()
```

Is it possible to change the value of variable in decortor?

In this case, I want to reset `counter` to `0`, like

```py
def reset():
    print(f'{reset.counter}: {reset.matter}')
    if reset.counter == 12:
        reset.counter = 0
```

But the code above doesn't work for me.

Any suggestion?

Also, I want to change members of Decorator like `schedules` and `matters`

### Solution:

Thanks for @ShadowRanger 's advice, inspire me a lot.

There is a conciser way to deal with this, shown as below:

```py
from collections import deque
from functools import wraps

def EventCounter(schedules, matters):
    if not (schedules and matters):
        raise ValueError("schedules and matters must be non-empty.")

    def wrap_func(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            wrapper.schedules = deque(wrapper.schedules)
            wrapper.matters = deque(wrapper.matters)
            if wrapper.schedules and wrapper.counter == wrapper.schedules[0]:
                wrapper.schedules.popleft()
                if wrapper.matters and len(wrapper.matters) != 1: # keep the last matter
                    wrapper.matters.popleft()
            wrapper.schedule = wrapper.schedules[0] if wrapper.schedules else None
            wrapper.matter = wrapper.matters[0] if wrapper.matters else None
            wrapper.counter += 1
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        wrapper.counter = 0  # Initialize wrapper.counter to zero before returning it
        wrapper.schedules = deque(schedules)
        wrapper.matters = deque(matters)
        return wrapper
    return wrap_func

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @EventCounter([2, 4, 8, 16], [0, 1, 2, 3])
    def reset():
        print(f'{reset.counter}: {reset.matter}')
        if reset.counter == 12:
            reset.counter = 0
            reset.schedules = [1,5,7,11]
            reset.matters = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    for _ in range(30):
        reset()
```

Comment: if you want to do that I think you need to store the counter on `f` instead of `wrapper`. maybe other changes needed too

Comment: @Anentropic: Putting it on `f` will mean it's *not* an attribute of the decorated `reset` function. It should be on `wrapper` (otherwise they'll have to drill through the resulting `reset` [really `wrapper`] to find the original function to reset it), it just shouldn't *also* be on the `EventCounter` instance.

Comment: Side-note: Assuming you're not writing code to run on Python 2 (and no one really should be nowadays), you can simplify `class EventCounter(object):` to just `class EventCounter:`. Explicitly inheriting from `object` was only needed on Python 2 to distinguish new-style classes from old-style classes; Python 3 only has new-style, so you inherit from `object` implicitly anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `int`s are immutable, and you're maintaining `wrapper.counter` and `self.counter` separately, resetting `wrapper.counter` to `self.counter` on each call (undoing your attempt to reset it via the wrapper). In this case, there is no real benefit to maintaining `self.counter` as an instance variable (the `EventCounter` object is discarded after decoration completes; it technically exists thanks to closing on `self` in `wrapper`, but accessing it would be nuts; frankly, the whole class is unnecessary and all of this could be done with simple closures), so the simplest solution is to store a single copy of the counter solely on the wrapper function:

```
from functools import wraps

class EventCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, schedules=None, matters=None):
        # Remove definition of self.counter
        self.schedules = schedules
        self.matters = matters
        if not isinstance(schedules, list) or not isinstance(matters, list):
            raise ValueError("schedules and matter must be list.")
        if not all([schedules, matters]):
            raise ValueError("Need to set schedules and matters both.")

    def __call__(self, f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.schedules:
                if wrapper.counter == self.schedules[0]:  # work solely in terms of wrapper.counter
                    self.schedules.pop(0)
                    if self.matters:
                        self.matters.pop(0)
            # No need to copy to/from wrapper.counter here
            wrapper.schedule = self.schedules[0] if self.schedules else None
            wrapper.matter = self.matters[0] if self.matters else None
            wrapper.counter += 1
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper.counter = 0  # Initialize wrapper.counter to zero before returning it
        return wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @EventCounter([2, 4, 8, 16], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    def reset():
        print(f'{reset.counter}: {reset.matter}')
        if reset.counter == 12:
            reset.counter = 0

    for _ in range(20):
        reset()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNNi9swEL37Vwx7iZya4GTLUhYMC8te99hLCEJxRhu1smQkeZdS9renUiI7luO2OunjzZunmTftL3fU6v504kY3wDtVO62lBdG02jj4MKy1WVZLZi28vKNyz7pTDg3R@x9Yu/wxA78OyIFSoYSjlFiUvABbH/HQSbTVq1ZYQMOcD7ucYlRYAbwasFBd41JIDPeAuBueBQelHQgrlHVM1UgGigKksC4HbaaQSBIBVzlhGSYswncmO3wxRhtyd9XH1CEKgKazDvZ4Zljd5VM9TEqyHSmJGXf/TfaKeACn/bcdzCW2sNfuGDKOSl/7dEPp@SjH07mDhF/1hYBw2fomLpl589qWy58fYTfR5n@Stid9jpDItaovxoCqmkRty91t4G3vV61uSZnPInslsQLzdFOvzBH2YvusMCP29t@A0jcpOHeWLBqiSrKPifrG/ZumL@CXCtapR9B1RgG/aVf2N4oKymwSHSFZJoJfFGuQ0tCrBaUNE4rSxaWqT8mUbzcFfC3gWwHrh10B29JvCvCX9/5@lw8ONOjtSkb@aY1QjvDF7/NLL@zzEeLFpSSfi2RuEmwQt95MpiUF@F@en7kfcApC@WlSb0g25UhIVJadTn8A)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Another question is whether can I change `schedules` and `matters` ?

Comment: As written, not easily (you'd have to drill through the closure scope stuff to get it). But you could do `wrapper.schedules = self.schedules` and `wrapper.matters = self.matters` in `__call__`, after defining `wrapper`, just like I added the `wrapper.counter = 0`. This will make them aliases of each other; since they're both `list`s, as long as you don't rebind the either attribute (only using mutating operations like method calls and indexing/slice operations, not reassignment), they'll refer to the same `list` forever.

Comment: @NEET: Just for completeness, after declaring your class unnecessary, [the purely closure-based version of your code (also using `deque` for efficient `popleft`)](https://tio.run/##fVJNT4QwEL33V0z2BKhkjTcTEhOzV49ejDEIg0ssbe2Hm/31WEr5KB/20JCZ997Me1Rc9Zmzh7atJG@g4JRioWvOFNSN4FJDiT8GietWhhWaczr2LjIXipASKzj9ItPP3DCNMlLFGUtDUd1Ck2tbUfEjAXvGBmS98ASNHcDDx/ZAd826AsY1TBzIWbmY0B2Z1wrhNacGT1JyGR02GdAYpeETrSi7w0boa3qIiVPpHHXmPjrLUXfN5J@c7b46FgeGsPaTXH5Z60nyfem@ZlTvIlzH09KiTw@ybAK8Hd9DdpBiKrigWOkoXmHsFG9zzZ8FvaMwrDRMgnCl0ANSm/YLZ7gp0Q@yAn6ipw//4H/yEMlNBvcBQKI2krkXuYqbkD2ZDI5kz6KaeyTbLtRkgyw28UCyKLkH1LZ/)